# Trouble with Mysql connection in my C program(Bad handshake)

Tags: mysql, c, linux

I am writing a Console program in C(linux) that operated on a Mysql Database.
My development linux box is ubuntu 10.10 having this mysql: (mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.1)
My deployment machine is zenwalk having this Mysql:(mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.56, for slackware-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 5.1).

When I compile the program and run it on the development box, it connects with no problem but when I transfer the executable program to the deployment machine and run it, it gives this error:
1043- Bad Handshake.

Can Anybody help me with this problem and let me know how to solve it?
Thank you 
vahid

Comment: There's not much we can do blindfolded. Also, who's vahid?

Comment: I think you should update your C library that you use to operate with MySQL. Try to search it in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

[Here you have a description of your error](http://atmail.com/kb/2008/mysql-error-bad-handshake/). The problem seams to be a different version between client library and server you are trying to connect

Comment: I guess at the moment my problem lies somewhere else than client server issue. I don't know what that is(i'm working on it), but I am sure my client server relations are good as brothers :) thank u for all the comments